# Merging multiple rows with same column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssms

What is the most efficient method to combine multiple rows of values with the same column in SQL Server?

data table

| category | segment | payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 1425 |
| 01 | B | 7647 |
| 01 | A | 6164 |
| 01 | B | 3241 |

And I'm trying to achieve the following result

| category | segment | payment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | 1425+6164 |
| 01 | B | 7647+3241 |

I want to merge the rows when the category and segment are same.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: A simple aggregation should do the trick.    Select category,segment,payment=sum(payment) from yourtable group by category,segment

Comment: do you want sum or actual string value with `+` inside?

Comment: Mysql is a quit different DBMS. Removed irrelevant tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use This

```
SELECT category,segment,payment = STUFF((
                                SELECT '+' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,payment)
                                FROM TABLENAME t
                                WHERE t.category = TABLENAME.category AND t.segment = TABLENAME.segment                               
                                FOR XML PATH('')
                                ), 1, 1, '')
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY category,segment
```

if you get payment with + sign then use stuff like this.

```
SELECT category,segment,SUM(payment) as payment
FROM TABLENAME 
GROUP BY category,segment
```

if you want sum then remove stuff and use `Sum(payment)` only.

Answer (score 2):

if you want actual total, then you can aggregate and summarize:

```
select category, segment, sum(payment)
from table
group by category, segment
```

if you want string, you can try something like that (for mysql):

```
select category, segment, GROUP_CONCAT(payment SEPARATOR '+')
from table
group by category, segment
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SUM aggregate function with a GROUP BY clause like so:

```
SELECT category, segment, SUM(payment) AS 'payment'
FROM table
GROUP BY category, segment
```

Answer (score 1):

your table

```
 declare @t TABLE (
   category int  NOT NULL 
  ,segment  NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
  ,payment  int  NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'A',1425);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'B',7647);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'A',6164);
INSERT INTO @t(category,segment,payment) VALUES (01,'B',3241);
```

if you want payment column as string then use following

```
SELECT
category, 
segment,
    STRING_AGG(cast(payment as nvarchar(50)),'+') 
        WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY category) payment
FROM
   @t T
GROUP BY
    category,segment
```

if you want payment column as NUMBER then use following

```
SELECT
category, 
segment,
SUM(payment) AS payment 
FROM
   @t T
GROUP BY
    category,segment
```